# Prometheus alert for flink failed job?

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus

I'm trying to monitor the availability of my flink jobs using Prometheus alerts.

I have tried with the flink_jobmanager_job_uptime/downtime metrics but they don't seem to fit since they just stop being emmited after the job has failed/finished.
I have already been pointed out to the numRunningJobs metric in order to alert of a missing job. I don't want to use this solution since I would have to update my prometheus config each time i want to deploy a new job.

Has anyone managed to create this alert of a Flink failed job using Prometheus?

Answer (score 1):

This pattern might do what your looking for.

```
count(flink_jobmanager_job_uptime offset 5m ) by (job_name) unless count(flink_jobmanager_job_uptime) by (job_name) > 0
```

Only triggers the alert if the metric was previously available then stopped. Works with multiple jobs using `count() by (job_name)`

`offset` would be how long the query looks back for valid data and how long it stays firing.

For long running jobs I would say `1d` would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus has an [absent()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#absent) function that will return 1 if the metric don't exist. So, you can just set the alert expression to something like

```
absent(flink_jobmanager_job_uptime) == 1
```